# class 'WP_Block_Supports' not found

Tags: php, wordpress

Today, i was updating wordpress new version 5.6.2, after that, database update but i have some problem with this:

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'WP_Block_Supports' not found in /home/------/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287

im looking a solution for this Warning
how to fix this problem.

thank you
for anybody can help me to fix this problem

Comment: Check this article - it might be useful - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-3711/